# Magento: <action method="unsetChild"> Not removing a block

Tags: magento, block, magento-1.7

I switch the display of `Wishlist_Sidebar` from right to left, using the following codes, but the sidebar remains in both right and left sidebar.

```
<reference name="right">                
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>wishlist_sidebar</name></action>
    //.....
</reference>
<reference name="left">
     <action method="insert"><blockName>wishlist_sidebar</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

How to fix this problem

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the unsetChild function might operate using the alias (the `as` attribute rather than the `name` attribute. Try using...

```
<reference name="right">                
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>wishlist</name></action>
    //.....
</reference>
```

Comment: ?!? what the heck are you supposed to do when the block has been added without an as="" then?? .. Magento.. holy crap.. without an as :D

Comment: I haven't tested but AFAIK, if there is no `as` attribute, then the `name` will suffice.

Comment: Correct, if `as` is absent, `name` is used instead.